# How do I move Tezos blockchain data to a separate partition?

Tags: node, tezos-client

I have setup my Tezos node on my server with pretty much default settings. But now the `~/.tezos-node/context` and `~/.tezos-node/store` directories are getting quite large with all the blockchain data.

How can I move this data to a separate partition on a separate harddisk drive and tell the Tezos node to use that instead?

Answer (score 2):

You can move the node config file and context dir to a different folder and use the ‘—data-dir’ option of the tezos node to point there when you start your node

For more details you can look here

https://tezos.gitlab.io/tezos/introduction/howto.html

Alternatively just move the context to another drive and create a symlink in your tezos directory

Comment: Can you expand on this? I don't want to move my config file. Just the big blockchain data.

Comment: I believe you need to move the config file too. Alternatively you can just symlink the context folder to some other location. I edited my answer to add this alternative.